# Give an example of a group that does have subgroups of order 1,2,3,4,5,6, but does not have subgroups of order 7 or 8

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I was thinking Z6 under addition mod 6 and each element is a subgroup. But then I can't find subgroups with order 4 and 5.

Comment: You won't, because of Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: @Bernard Why does Lagrange's Theorem preclude this?

Comment: $\mathbf Z/6\mathbf Z$ has order $6$, and neither $4$ nor $5$ are divisors of $6$, if I'm not mistaken. You need a group of order a multiple of $20$

Comment: @Bernard Oh, I see, you were commenting just about OP's suggestion of $\Bbb Z / 6 \Bbb Z$, not the existence of a group with this property in general.

Comment: @Travis: yes, we were mutually mistaken ;o)

Answer (score 3):

What about Z/5ZxZ/12Z. Perhaps the simplest (?) example, as your group must have an order divisible by 5, 4, 3

Comment: In other words, the cyclic group of order $60$.

Comment: @DerekHolt So Z60 will be my group?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** What are the orders of the subgroups of the symmetric group $S_n$ on $n$ objects for small $n$? Note that any group with the given property must contain an element of order $5$ and so has order divisible by $5$; what is the smallest $n$ for which this is true for $S_n$?

Alternatively, what are the orders of the subgroups of the cyclic group $C_n$?

Comment: The first one is a really hard question, and I don't see it leading to an easy answer here.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft You're right, of course, and the original wording was perhaps misleading: I intended for the hint to suggest working out the answer (at least as far as necessary) for small $n$, which is entirely tractable and which leads to an example quickly; in particular, I was not suggesting OP first try to understand the problem for general $n$.

Comment: @Travis So you are saying the smallest n for Sn to have order 5?